# How to spool output from SQL*PLUS to appear in single line with 1 space in between them?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a table with 20 rows. I want to spool the rows into a text file where rows come side by side in one line and have one space in between to keep them separated. I intend to create a tar.gz file by keeping them in one line.

**Sample data:**

`col1`
`------`

`file1`
`file2`
`file3`

**expected output:**

`tar cvzf tarfile.tgz file1 file2 file3`

Comment: Please provide provide your expected output and some sample data.

Comment: added some description please go through and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query to get all rows in single row.

```
SELECT 'tar cvzf tarfile.tgz ' || LISTAGG(col1, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1)
FROM your_table_name;
```

**Sample Data:**

```
SQL> select * from tbl1;

COL1
--------------------
file 1
file 2
file 3
```

**Output:**

```
tar cvzf file 1 file 2 file 3
```

To spool-

```
SQL> set heading off
SQL> spool 'output.txt'
SQL> SELECT 'tar cvzf tarfile.tgz ' || LISTAGG(col1, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1)
     FROM your_table_name;
SQL> spool off
```

[Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ac5fe96c4f5bc6530da499a2ea74fb9c) is the fiddle.

Comment: Command works perfectly but I am getting kind of a warning message  **tar: Removing leading `/' from member names**

Comment: It is related to the OS command `tar`. You might have unsupported commands in your output. Please verify that output only contains supported commands. Or post that as question in unix/liux site.

Comment: I sorted that out. Now a new error is coming. I do not know if this is ignorable.  **tar: /u01/app/oracle/oradata/db5/sysaux01.dbf: file changed as we read it**  I plan to use this tar.gz for database recovery purposes so will this cause problems?

Comment: If you are looking at database recovery, I suggest you lean about RMAN

Comment: @GirishSunkara: yes, that will cause a lot of problems. Oracle has its own backup tool. Check the [Database Backup and Recovery User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/toc.htm)